# Need help implementing a code that will save the input entered by the user and the output of the answer in a text file

Tags: c++, computer-science

I've created a code that will convert a decimal to a floating point and a floating-point to a decimal. All I need is to add a code that I'm not sure how to add and where to add it. But I need to implement a code that will save all of the user's input and the output of the answers saved onto a text file such as notepad. The following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*************************/
void decimal_to_IEEE754()
{
   /* declare local variables */
   float decimal_number;
   int exponent = 0;
   int bit[32];
   for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) bit[i] = 0;

   /* prompt for floating point decimal number */
   printf("\nEnter the decimal representation: ");
   scanf("%f", &decimal_number);
   if (decimal_number == 0)
   {
       printf("\n*** Sign: 0");
       printf("\n*** Biased exponent : 00000000");
       printf("\n*** Mantissa : 00000000000000000000000");
       printf("\n***The IEEE - 754 representation is : 0.000000");
       return;
   }
      
   /* Check for 0--if so, print result */
   /* Print sign: if number>0, sign is 0, else 1 */
   if (decimal_number < 0){
       printf("\n*** Sign: %d", 1);
       bit[31] = 1;
   }
   else{
       bit[31] = 0;
       printf("\n*** Sign: %d", 0);
   }

   /* take absolute value of number before generating significand */
   if (decimal_number < 0) decimal_number = -decimal_number;

   /* Normalize number:
   while number >2, divide by 2, increment exponent
   while number <1, multiply by 2, decrement exponent
   */
   while (decimal_number > 2)
   {
       decimal_number = decimal_number / 2;
       exponent = exponent + 1;
   }
   while (decimal_number < 1)
   {
       decimal_number = decimal_number * 2;
       exponent = exponent - 1;
   }

   /* Bias exponent by 127 and print each bit in binary with 8-iteration for-loop*/
   exponent = exponent + 127;
   printf("\n*** Biased exponent: ");
   int i = 23;
   while (exponent)
   {
       bit[i] = exponent % 2;
       exponent = exponent / 2;
       i++;
   }
   for (i = 30; i >=23; i--)
   {
       printf("%d", bit[i]);
   }
   /* Hide 1 and print significand in binary with 23-iteration for-loop*/
   decimal_number = decimal_number - 1;
   printf("\n*** Mantissa: ");
   for (i = 22; i >= 0;i--)
   {
       decimal_number = decimal_number * 2;
       if (decimal_number>=1)
       {
           bit[i] = 1;
           decimal_number = decimal_number - 1;
       }
       else
       {
           bit[i] = 0;
       }
       printf("%d", bit[i]);
   }

   /* Print IEEE-754 representation */
   printf("\n*** IEEE HEX: ");
   for (i = 31; i > 0; i = i - 4)
   {
             if (bit[i] == 1 && bit[i - 1] == 1 && bit[i - 2] == 1 && bit[i - 3] == 1) printf("F");
       else if (bit[i] == 1 && bit[i - 1] == 1 && bit[i - 2] == 1 && bit[i - 3] == 0) printf("E");
       else if (bit[i] == 1 && bit[i - 1] == 1 && bit[i - 2] == 0 && bit[i - 3] == 1) printf("D");
       else if (bit[i] == 1 && bit[i - 1] == 1 && bit[i - 2] == 0 && bit[i - 3] == 0) printf("C");
       else if (bit[i] == 1 && bit[i - 1] == 0 && bit[i - 2] == 1 && bit[i - 3] == 1) printf("B");
       else if (bit[i] == 1 && bit[i - 1] == 0 && bit[i - 2] == 1 && bit[i - 3] == 0) printf("A");
       else if (bit[i] == 1 && bit[i - 1] == 0 && bit[i - 2] == 0 && bit[i - 3] == 1) printf("9");
       else if (bit[i] == 1 && bit[i - 1] == 0 && bit[i - 2] == 0 && bit[i - 3] == 0) printf("8");
       else if (bit[i] == 0 && bit[i - 1] == 1 && bit[i - 2] == 1 && bit[i - 3] == 1) printf("7");
       else if (bit[i] == 0 && bit[i - 1] == 1 && bit[i - 2] == 1 && bit[i - 3] == 0) printf("6");
       else if (bit[i] == 0 && bit[i - 1] == 1 && bit[i - 2] == 0 && bit[i - 3] == 1) printf("5");
       else if (bit[i] == 0 && bit[i - 1] == 1 && bit[i - 2] == 0 && bit[i - 3] == 0) printf("4");
       else if (bit[i] == 0 && bit[i - 1] == 0 && bit[i - 2] == 1 && bit[i - 3] == 1) printf("3");
       else if (bit[i] == 0 && bit[i - 1] == 0 && bit[i - 2] == 1 && bit[i - 3] == 0) printf("2");
       else if (bit[i] == 0 && bit[i - 1] == 0 && bit[i - 2] == 0 && bit[i - 3] == 1) printf("1");
       else if (bit[i] == 0 && bit[i - 1] == 0 && bit[i - 2] == 0 && bit[i - 3] == 0) printf("0");
   }
   return;
}

/***********************************************************************/
void IEEE754_to_decimal()
{
   /* declare local variables */
   char IEEE_char[20];
   int bit[32];
   float fraction = 0.0;
   int exponent=0;
   float number;
   /* prompt for IEEE-754 representation */
   printf("\nEnter the IEEE-754 representation:");
   scanf("%s", IEEE_char);

   /* check for special cases: NaN
   if so, print and return */
   int j = 0;
   int NaN_flag=0;
   while (IEEE_char[j] && j < 20)
   {
       if (j >= 8) { NaN_flag = 1; break; }
       if (!((IEEE_char[j] >= 'A' && IEEE_char[j] <= 'F') || (IEEE_char[j]>='0' && IEEE_char[j]<='9')))
       {
           NaN_flag = 1; break;
       }
       j++;
   }

   if (NaN_flag == 1)
   {
       printf("\n*** Sign: -");
       printf("\n*** Special case: NaN");
       return;
   }

   /*binary bit calculation*/
   j = 31;
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
       if (IEEE_char[i] == 'F'){ bit[j] = 1; bit[j - 1] = 1; bit[j - 2] = 1; bit[j - 3] = 1; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == 'E'){ bit[j] = 1; bit[j - 1] = 1; bit[j - 2] = 1; bit[j - 3] = 0; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == 'D'){ bit[j] = 1; bit[j - 1] = 1; bit[j - 2] = 0; bit[j - 3] = 1; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == 'C'){ bit[j] = 1; bit[j - 1] = 1; bit[j - 2] = 0; bit[j - 3] = 0; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == 'B'){ bit[j] = 1; bit[j - 1] = 0; bit[j - 2] = 1; bit[j - 3] = 1; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == 'A'){ bit[j] = 1; bit[j - 1] = 0; bit[j - 2] = 1; bit[j - 3] = 0; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '9'){ bit[j] = 1; bit[j - 1] = 0; bit[j - 2] = 0; bit[j - 3] = 1; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '8'){ bit[j] = 1; bit[j - 1] = 0; bit[j - 2] = 0; bit[j - 3] = 0; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '7'){ bit[j] = 0; bit[j - 1] = 1; bit[j - 2] = 1; bit[j - 3] = 1; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '6'){ bit[j] = 0; bit[j - 1] = 1; bit[j - 2] = 1; bit[j - 3] = 0; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '5'){ bit[j] = 0; bit[j - 1] = 1; bit[j - 2] = 0; bit[j - 3] = 1; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '4'){ bit[j] = 0; bit[j - 1] = 1; bit[j - 2] = 0; bit[j - 3] = 0; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '3'){ bit[j] = 0; bit[j - 1] = 0; bit[j - 2] = 1; bit[j - 3] = 1; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '2'){ bit[j] = 0; bit[j - 1] = 0; bit[j - 2] = 1; bit[j - 3] = 0; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '1'){ bit[j] = 0; bit[j - 1] = 0; bit[j - 2] = 0; bit[j - 3] = 1; }
       else if (IEEE_char[i] == '0'){ bit[j] = 0; bit[j - 1] = 0; bit[j - 2] = 0; bit[j - 3] = 0; }
       j = j - 4;
   }

   /* Mask biased exponent and significand from number */
   for (int i = 0; i <= 22; i++)
   {
       fraction = (fraction + bit[i]) / ((float)2.0);
   }
   for (int i = 30; i >= 23; i--)
   {
       exponent = exponent * 2 + bit[i];
   }

   /* check for special cases: 0, -0, +infinity, -infinity,NaN
   if so, print and return */
   if (exponent == 255 && fraction == (float)0.0)
   {
       if (bit[31]) {
           printf("\n*** Sign: -");
           printf("\n*** Special case: -infinity");
       }
       else
       {
           printf("\n*** Sign: +");
           printf("\n*** Special case: +infinity");
       }
       return;
   }
   else if (exponent == 255 && fraction != (float)0.0)
   {
       printf("\n*** Sign: -");
       printf("\n*** Special case: NaN");
       return;
   }
   else if (exponent == 0 && fraction == (float)0.0)
   {
       if (bit[31]) {
           printf("\n*** Sign: -");
           printf("\n*** Special case: -0");
       }
       else
       {
           printf("\n*** Sign: +");
           printf("\n*** Special case: +0");
       }
       return;
   }
   /* Mask sign from number: if sign=0, print "+", else print "-" */
   printf("\n*** Sign: ");
   if (bit[31] == 1) printf("-");
   else            printf("+");


   /* If biased exponent=0, number is denormalized with unbiased exponent of -126,
   print denormalized number as fraction * 2^(-126), return */
   if (exponent == 0)
   {
       printf("\n*** denormalized number: %f*2^(-126)", fraction);
       return;
   }
   /* Unbias exponent by subtracting 127 and print */
   exponent = exponent - 127;
   printf("\n*** Unbiased exponent: %d", exponent);
   /* Add hidden 1 and print normalized decimal number */
   fraction = fraction + 1;
   printf("\n*** Normalized decimal: %f", fraction);
   /* Print decimal number */
   number = fraction*pow(2.0, (double)exponent);
   if (bit[31]) printf("\n*** Decimal: -%f", number);
   else         printf("\n*** Decimal: %f", number);

   return;

}

int main()
{
   /* declare local variables */
   int selection=0;
   /* until user chooses to quit, prompt for choice and select appropriate function */
   while (selection != 3)
   {
       printf("\nFloating-point conversion:");
       printf("\n1) Decimal to IEEE-754 conversion");
       printf("\n2) IEEE-754 to Decimal conversion");
       printf("\n3) Exit");
       printf("\nEnter selection: ");
       scanf("%d", &selection);
       switch (selection)
       {
           case 1:
           {
                      decimal_to_IEEE754();
                      break;
           }
           case 2:
           {
                      IEEE754_to_decimal();
                      break;
           }
           case 3:
           {
                      break;
           }
       }
   }
   printf("\n*** Program Terminated Normally");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Notepad is not a text file, it's another application like Word or Wordpad.

Comment: Since you are using the C language I/O streams, look up `fprintf`, `FILE`, and `fputs`.

Comment: You could pass a `FILE *` to your functions and use `fprintf` instead of `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file I/O operations availabe in C.

```
    #include<stdlib.h>




    int main()
    {
       /* declare local variables */
       int selection=0;
       /* until user chooses to quit, prompt for choice and select appropriate function */

       // Setup File pointer
       FILE* outputfile;      // File pointer for input file

       outputfile   = fopen ("fileout.txt", "w+");    // open a file with filename as fileout.txt in read/write mode


       while (selection != 3)
       {
           printf("\nEnter selection: ");
           scanf("%d", &selection);
           fprintf(outputfile,"%d\t",selection);   // write the input value to file with tab charecter for seperation
           switch (selection)
           {
               case 1:
               {
                          decimal_to_IEEE754(outputfile);
                          break;
               }
               case 2:
               {
                          IEEE754_to_decimal(outputfile);
                          break;
               }
               case 3:
               {
                          break;
               }
           }
       }

       fclose(outputfile);   // close te file


       printf("\n*** Program Terminated Normally");
       return 0;
    }
```

Important point, given the nature of your function declarations, which does not return any values, So you need to modify the functions to accept the filepointer as a input parameter in order to write the values when the respective function in called.

```
  void decimal_to_IEEE754(FILE* outputfile);
void IEEE754_to_decimal(FILE* outputfile);
```

The inside the function, you can use the same function call to write the output value to the file using the same logic used for printing them.

in IEEE754_to_decimal()

```
fprintf(outputfile,"%f\n",number); //  value followed by newline at end
```

For writting the char values to file, you can use the '%c' instead of '%f' in fprintf function inside decimal_to_IEEE754().